# Arrangement of "list items" in listview using html

Tags: html, css, image, listview, cordova

This is my first "phonegap" application  project, so done with the listview in html based on the requirement but listview is not properly formatted (ie one below the other), how to make the items to display one below the other. please help me.

here's my code for listview

```
<div>
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
<li><a href="#">
    <img src="images/c3.jpeg" align="left">
    <h3>CONGRATULATIONS</h3>
    </a>
       </li>

<li><a href="#">
    <img src="images/c2.jpeg" align="left">
    <h3>HOLYDAY</h3>
    </a>
</li>

<li><a href="#">
    <img src="images/card1.jpeg" align="left">
    <h3> I'M SORRY </h3>
    </a>
</li>

<li><a href="#">
    <img src="images/c4.jpg" align="left">
    <h3> HAPPY BIRTHDAY </h3>
    </a>
</li>

<li><a href="#">
    <img src="images/c5.jpg" align="left">
    <h3> MISSING U</h3>
    </a>
</li>

<li><a href="#">
    <img src="images/images.jpg" align="left">
    <h3> ENGAGEMENT</h3>
    </a>
</li>
```

```
 ![device output][1]
```

[image]

Comment: I feel there's no question here, also you cannot use `br` as a `ul` direct child

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have edited my question and added the screen shot of device output @Mr.Alien

Comment: Are you using float: left?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you cannot use `<br />`  as direct `ul` child and secondly am sure you are using `float: left;` for the images which are inside `li` tag and thus it is spoiling the layout. Inorder to fix it, use the CSS property block below

```
ul.class_name li {
   overflow: hidden;
   /* Other styles goes here */
}
```

Just assign a class to `ul` element, replace the `.class_name` in CSS with the class you assigned to the `ul` element in your HTML.

Also, you can use the below declaration to self clear the parent element like

```
.clear:after {
   display: table;
   content: "";
   clear: both;
}
```

This will self clear the parent element just like `overflow: hidden;` does, but in a better way.

Comment: i removed <br> and <align left> tags now images and texts are appearing one below the other, but want images and text to appear in same line. @Mr.Alien

Comment: @DD. just keep the way it is, and simply use the above answer in your css, and see what it does, am not having much info about the phonegap but this happens when you don't clear your floating elements, so use the above ruleset with overflow hidden and see what it does, read my answer properly, atleast till here *...n CSS with the class you assigned to the ul element in your HTML.*

Comment: ok thanks alot for your answer :) i will follow it. @Mr.Alien